# Non-formatted error log in CodeIgniter 2

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, error-logging, errorformat

I am currently running a `websocket` daemon in CodeIgniter 2. The daemon is started using `nohup` and runs in an eternal loop. The error output is formatted as HTML. However, I'd like to have the errors logged ***without HTML formatting***. Does CodeIgniter have an option to make this possible?

**EDIT:**
I am not only tracking errors. I am also saving a `websocket` log. The log contains functions that have been run and other useful information. I don't want to hide errors from the log though since they may be useful for tracking some errors. I want to log my custom `websocket` messages along with errors that may occur.

Daemon start command:

```
nohup php /usr/share/nginx/html/index.php websocket server > /var/log/websocket/$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") 2>&1 &
```

The errors in the log look like this:

```html
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR</p>
<p>Filename: core/Input.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 351</p>
```

Comment: `running in eternal loop`, you make it sound like it's being punished. You could use [strip_tags](https://php.net/strip_tags) or potentially use some regex to strip them out(although it's not really recommended to use regex for html parsing).

Comment: Show your `core/Input.php` file.

Comment: As mentioned I strongly think you should log errors seperately. You can follow my answer, suppress all errors and print the error in some better format, or email the errors to you, but this won't catch compile errors

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing things up a bit, There's the logs and there's the output produced by the page/script.

What you're doing is saving the output from the script into the log, all output, including php errors, notices, warnings and codeigniter's errors(unable to conenct to database).

Codeigniter doesn't have much to do with PHP errors as far as I know, which means this formatting actually comes from the php process itself, you can't prevent this format as far as I know.

If you want to catch all errors, you could suppress all errors and use php's native `error_get_last` method, this returns something like this :

```
Array
(
    [type] => 8
    [message] => Undefined variable: a
    [file] => C:\WWW\index.php
    [line] => 2
)
```

However, should you have a compile error, this method won't work as it needs the code to compile first.

Apache should save automatically the errors for you, I'm pretty sure that can be configured in php.ini but I haven't done that in a while.

In conclusion, I don't think saving the entire output to a log would be the best way to track errors.

Ref to docs : http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php

Comment: I am not tracking just errors. I am saving websocket log. It logs functions it runs and other useful information. I don't want to hide errors from the log thou since it may be useful tracking some errors. I want to log my custom websocket messages along with errors that may occur.

Comment: I think you should log the errors separately completely. consider a high traffic website, do you really want to sift through millions of records simply to get to that single php error that one guy encountered that one time? plus, how would you know in real time there's an error? Error tracking/watching is best done separately